# Create a pie chart of multiple columns

Tags: r, sum, multiple-columns, pie-chart, percentage

I want to create a pie chart of multiple columns. This somewhat unusual constellation is necessary for the evaluation of a large survey. The answers were always yes/no, with several columns overlapping with yes/no, so simply merging them would change the statement. In the end, an absolute number of yes answers would be needed per associated column in total.

#example table:

```
x <- read.csv2(file = textConnection("a;b;c;d
yes;no;yes;no
no;no;yes;no
no;no;yes;no
no;yes;no;no
no;yes;no;no
no;no;no;yes
no;no;no;yes
no;no;yes;yes
no;no;yes;yes
no;yes;yes;no
yes;yes;no;no
yes;yes;no;no
yes;yes;no;no
yes;yes;yes;no
yes;no;yes;no
yes;no;yes;yes
yes;no;yes;yes
no;no;no;yes
no;no;no;no
no;no;no;no
no;no;yes;no
no;no;yes;no
yes;no;no;no
yes;no;no;no"))
```

In the end, there should be a pie chart showing in percent the a's amount of yes (x%), b's amount of yes (y%)... and so on.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reshape from wide-to-long, keep only "yes" rows, then get counts and plot:

```
d <- stack(x)
tbl <- table(d[ d$values == "yes", "ind" ])
pie(tbl, labels = paste(names(tbl), "-",
                        round(prop.table(tbl) * 100), "%"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This shows the absolute number of "yes" for each column.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

x %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
  summarise(res = sum(value == "yes"), .by = name) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x="", y=res, fill=name)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1) +
  coord_polar("y", start=0) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = res), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), 
            color = "white", size=6) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set1") +
  theme_void()
```

[image]